# Glassfish 3.1.2 and Eclipse Indigo Plugin

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, glassfish

My freshly installed Eclipse Indigo SR2 with the new Glassfish 3.1.2 Plugin creates on every start a new "Internal GlassFish 3.1.2" Server.

How can I prevent this behavior? Does somebody already use this configuration?

Comment: You may want to file an issue @ http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS.

Comment: @vkraemer I've created the issue as http://bit.ly/z0WAhg .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and my workaround is uninstall the "*Glassfish 3.1.2 Application Server Runtime*" from the Eclipse. ***Please make a full backup for our Eclipse first.***

It can be done by the following step: -

1. Go to "*Help*" menu ---> "*About Eclipse*".
2. Click "*Installation Details*" button.
3. The system will display the "*Eclipse Installation Details*" windows.
4. Go to "*Installed Software*" tab.
5. Find the "*Glassfish 3.1.2 Application Server Runtime*" in the list and click it. Please note it is sorted alphabetically.
6. Click "*Uninstall...*" button
7. The "*Uninstall*" windows will display, please review and click the "*Finish*" button for uninstalling.

Edit: We need to start the Eclipse with "*clean*" option after it is uninstalled.

I download the Glassfish 3.1.2 Open Source Edition form [here](http://bit.ly/zEyXM3) and install to my machine. Then register the new installed Glassfish 3.1.2 to the Eclipse.

Regarding to my opinion, I thought that it would be nice if I use the Glassfish out side the Eclipse plugin / workspace folder.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been recently fixed - here is the guide how to install the new fixed runtime plugin: https://blogs.oracle.com/piotrik/entry/bug_fix_for_eclipse_runtime