# new glassfish server created each time I launch Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Glassfish 3.1.2 and Eclipse Indigo Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665779/glassfish-3-1-2-and-eclipse-indigo-plugin)

I've just installed Eclipse (Indigo) and GlassFish 3.1.2.  Every time I start Eclipse it creates a new instance of a glassfish server runtime environment.  So I end up with a server list that looks like the following:

```
Internal GlassFish 3.1.2
Internal GlassFish 3.1.2 (2)
Internal GlassFish 3.1.2 (3)
Internal GlassFish 3.1.2 (4)
```

and so on ...

I've extensively searched the eclipse UI and googled this issue and I can't find the (presumably) preference setting where I can correct this.

thanks in advance.